# I can't import a project from github repository to stackblitz if I use firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, github, firefox, stackblitz

> I log into statckbliz when trying to import the github project

[proyect github](https://github.com/nestdanchia/spinner)

> changing the address to

[addres stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/github/nestdanchia/spinner)
https://stackblitz.com/github/nestdanchia/spinner

> it doesn't show me anything and the console shows The next message

```js
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { _e: Error, name: "OpenFailedError", message: "InvalidStateError A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.\n InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.", inner: {…}, stack: "" }
​
_e: Error: 
​
inner: Object { _e: Error, name: "InvalidStateError", message: "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.\n InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.", … }
​​
_e: Error: 
​​
inner: DOMException: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.
​​
message: "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.\n InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations."
​​
name: "InvalidStateError"
​​
stack: 
​​
<get stack()>: function get()​​
<prototype>: Object { stack: "", … }
​
message: "InvalidStateError A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.\n InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations."
​
name: "OpenFailedError"
​
stack: ""
​
<prototype>: Object { stack: "", … }
```

> How can I fix it I use windows 11 firefox browser I looked for a solution but I can't find it
> .......................
> In Sandbox if I can import it. but it gives me an error when executing
> it, related to an import. In visual studio code the code is executed
> without problems

```js
import localeEsAr from '@angular/common/locales/es-AR';
Could not find module in path: '@angular/common/locales/es-AR' relative to '/src/app/app.module.ts'
```

From Microsoft Edge on stackblitz it runs perfectly:
[runs](https://stackblitz.com/github/nestdanchia/spinner)

Comment: It seems to work. Might be a random error thrown by stackblitz...

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. I'm also able to load the stackblitz with the github repo